# Unable to see a specific workspace to publish from desktop to service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using a SQL Server and I created a report. I would like to publish it to a specific workspace where I am a "Member".

But in the desktop I don't see this workspace when I try to publish the report.

What can I do ?

Comment: What sort of member? You maybe in a read only user role, or do not have a PBI Pro licence

Answer (score 0):

This happened when my password expired for Microsoft account, can you try log out and log in again with Power Bi. Otherwise check access from that workspace.